# Pandas drop_duplicates() not working after add a row to DataFrame when read from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drop-duplicates

My code like below:

```
indexing_file_path = 'indexing.csv'
if not os.path.exists(indexing_file_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame([['1111', '20200101', '20200101'], 
                       ['1112', '20200101', '20200101'], 
                       ['1113', '20200101', '20200101']], 
                       columns = ['nname', 'nstart', 'nend'])
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(indexing_file_path, header = 0)

print(df)
df.loc[len(df)] = ['1113', '20200202', '20200303']
# append() method not working either
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates('nname', keep = 'last', inplace = True)
print(df)
df.to_csv(indexing_file_path, index = False)
```

I want to keep the `nname` column unique in this file.

When the code run first time, it will save the records to csv file correctly, although the `1113` is not unique.

When the code run second time, it will save two `1113` rows to the csv file, because the DataFrame is created from a csv file.

After the third time run, it will always keep two `1113` rows.

Now I have a solution:

1, save to csv file with two `1113` row.

2, read the csv file again.

3, use `drop_duplicates` again.

4, save to csv file again.

Why the DataFrame created from a csv file is so different?

How can I save the unique row to csv file one time?

Comment: The first time the dataframe is created (not from file) all of the column types are object and drop_duplicates works. When the dataframe is created from a file all of the object types are int64, but when you do `df.loc[len(df)] = ['1113', '20200202', '20200303']`, the types become object and drop_duplicates doesn't work. If you insert `ints` instead of `str`, then drop_duplicates woks. Appending the new row, as in the answer below, maintains the types and drop_duplicates works.  A change in type causes drop_duplicate to not function properly.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I tried to change the dtypes to objects after I read csv file, and then use append method to add a row, but it's also not working. by the way, I want the `nname` column as string not int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my question now.

The reason is:

**When DataFrame is created from a csv file, pandas recognize the `nname` column as integer**

But, when I add `1113` row again, pandas recognize the new row `nname` as a string, so the integer `1113` is not equals the string `1113`, pandas will keep two row.

The solution is:

**Read csv file as string.**

```
df = pd.read_csv(indexing_file_path, header=0, dtype=str)
```